# Datomic newbie question - modelling related facts when one fact changes

Tags: data-modeling, datomic

If I have a customer entity and they move from an address at time t1 that has these facts:

- address_line_1 = "10 Downing St"
- address_line_2 = "Westminster"
- city = "London"

to a new address and time t2 with these facts:

- address_line_1 = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW"
- city = "Washington DC"

How do you avoid the address at t2 onwards looking like:

- address_line_1 = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW"
- address_line_2 = "Westminster"
- city = "Washington DC"

Options I can think of:

1. assert the fact at t2 that address_line_2 = "" to reset or blank it out.
2. have address as it's own entity an point to a new address entity that only has the two facts: address_line_1 = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW" and city = "Washington DC" asserted on it.
3. assert a new fact at t2 like "moved_house" = true to express that tehir address is different.

My thoughts:

- Option 1 seems to rely on "knowing" what's been set previously across all time that may no longer be true so you can blank them out.
- Option 2 seems best - but does mean more netities being defined than I was expecting.
- Option 3 seems yuck!

Anyone else's thoughts on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You could also retract the address_line_2 datom using a transaction function.

Comment: Either 1 or 2 will work.  I would prefer #2 since the address is a stand-alone "entity" (you would normally make Address a separate class in Java et al).

Comment: Thanks :) But what about my comment about option #1 "Option 1 seems to rely on "knowing" what's been set previously across all time that may no longer be true so you can blank them out." I am thinking more generally than for this address example. Option #2 seems more general - but see comment below on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use option 2 as component entities.

https://support.cognitect.com/hc/en-us/articles/215581418-Component-Attributes?mobile_site=true

Here is a sample:

```
;; schema
;;
(d/transact conn [{:db/ident      :client/address
                  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
                  :db/valueType   :db.type/ref
                  :db/isComponent true}
                  {:db/ident      :address/line1
                  :db/valueType   :db.type/string
                  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
                  {:db/ident      :address/country
                  :db/valueType   :db.type/string
                  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}])

;; create a new client with address - 1 Main Street
;;
(d/transact conn [{:db/id         (d/tempid :db.part/user -1)
                  :client/address {:address/line1   "1 Main Street"
                                   :address/country "USA"}}])

;; datomic will return you two entity id.  One is for :client/address
;; and another one for :address/line1 and :address/country
;;
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [*])
      :where [?e :client/address]]
    (d/db conn))
;; => [[{:db/id 17592186045418, :client/address {:db/id 17592186045419, :address/line1 "1 Main Street", :address/country "USA"}}]]

;; now update its client address to 9 Kings Road.
;;
(d/transact conn [{:db/id          17592186045418
                  :client/address {:address/line1 "9 Kings Road"}}])

;; 17592186045418 will then have a :client/address 
;; pointing to a new entity with the new address
;;
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [*])
      :where [?e :client/address]]
    (d/db conn))
;; => [[{:db/id 17592186045418, :client/address {:db/id 17592186045421, :address/line1 "9 Kings Road"}}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of component entities.I wonder how this would look when saving - how does Datomic distinguish between editing a typo in the address vs "moving" to a whole new address? Let me know if that deserves its own stack overflow question!

Comment: If you use the map interface, update transaction will be converted to a retract-and-add.  This means the component will be replaced by a new entity.